Error using Powershell's Invoke-Command with Filepath
I have a Powershell script 'hello-world.ps1', which is overly simple, it takes no arguments and simply writes some text to the console:
  Write-Host "Hello world"

With the command prompt, in the same folder as the script, I want to invoke this script using 'Invoke-Command'. I tried Invoke-Command {& .\hello-world.ps1} and that works. However, there is a FilePath option that seems more intuitive, so I'm trying
Invoke-Command -FilePath .\hello-world.ps1

This is basically the first example on the Microsoft documentation page.
However, I'm getting an error "Invoke-Command: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters." Specifying the absolute path to the script, which is on my local machine, also does not work.
Why can I not invoke the ps1 script using -FilePath?

Specifies a local script that this cmdlet runs on one or more remote computers, you don't have a remote

Duh, I should have read the docs a bit more carefully, I assumed that FilePath would work on a local machine.

Try changing directory to you current folder using CD.  What you did should work if the current folder is recognized.

Why do you want to use Invoke-Command?

In short: there's no need to use Invoke-Command for local calls; its primary use is for remoting. Local calls do not support the -FilePath parameter; to execute code locally, use & c:\path\to\your\file.ps1 or & { ... } to execute a group of commands.
See the linked duplicate for details.
